# NGINX user-friendly url without changing path in browser

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite or redirect an url to a user friendly url without changing the requested url in the browser ?

I want user to access the page :
example.com/dashboard/c7BIDZMJ96zh8jKgmTEcAugA22RDhGkH

Through url :
example.com/dashboard/nicedashboardname

I am using Nginx rewrite

```
location = /dashboard/nicedashboardname {
    rewrite ^/dashboard/nicedashboardname?$ /dashboard/c7BIDZMJ96zh8jKgmTEcAugA22RDhGkH break;
}
```

I need this because the Id of the non-user-friendly page can change over time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `rewrite` here… You can use `return`:

```
location = /dashboard/nicedashboardname {
    return 301 /dashboard/c7BIDZMJ96zh8jKgmTEcAugA22RDhGkH;
}
```

Comment: The return method behaves the same way. 
I would like the "redirect" transparent to the user so they don't bookmark the non-user-friendly url